# How do I change my code so it adds the data to column 2? Column 1 has my headings

Tags: google-sheets

Here is part of my code:

```
sheet.appendRow([new Date(),spending,description]);
sheet.getRange("B2:B").setNumberFormat('[$$]#,##0.00');
sheet.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy | HH:mm');
```

I've tried numerous methods but cannot seem to get the new data to be added at the top, after my headings which are in A1 and B1.

I've tried
sheet.getRange(2, 1)
sheet.insertRows(1)
function insertRowAtTop_v1(data, sheetName, targetRow)

But i think i've put them all in wrong.

Thank you!